# In pyspark how to define the schema for list of list with datatype

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I want col4 and col5 should comes as ArrayType they are coming as StringType. It is in pyspark.
I want to know how we can do this.

```
col4 --array (nullable = true)
      |-- element: IntegerType() (containsNull = true)
col5:--array (nullable = true)
      |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+---+-----------+
| id|      value|
+---+-----------+
|  1| [foo, foo]|
|  2|[bar, tooo]|
+---+-----------+

+---+-----------+---------------------+
|id |value      |TF_CUS(value)        |
+---+-----------+---------------------+
|1  |[foo, foo] |[[foo], [2]]         |
|2  |[bar, tooo]|[[bar, tooo], [1, 1]]|
+---+-----------+---------------------+

+---+-----------+---------------------+------+-----------+
|id |value      |TF_CUS               |col4  |col5       |
+---+-----------+---------------------+------+-----------+
|1  |[foo, foo] |[[foo], [2]]         |[2]   |[foo]      |
|2  |[bar, tooo]|[[bar, tooo], [1, 1]]|[1, 1]|[bar, tooo]|
+---+-----------+---------------------+------+-----------+
```

looking forward to see solutions 
        root
         |-- id: long (nullable = true)
         |-- value: array (nullable = true)
         |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
         |-- TF_CUS: array (nullable = true)
         |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)`enter code here`
         |-- col4: string (nullable = true)
         |-- col5: string (nullable = true)

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType

def TF_CUS(lista):
    from collections import Counter
    counts = (Counter(lista))
    return (list(counts.keys()), list(counts.values()))

TF_CUS_cols = udf(TF_CUS, ArrayType(StringType()))

df = sc.parallelize([(1, ["foo","foo"] ), (2, ["bar", "tooo"])]).toDF(["id", "value"])
df.show()
df.select("*", TF_CUS_cols(df["value"])).show(2, False)
df = df.select("*", TF_CUS_cols(df["value"]).alias("TF_CUS"))
df.withColumn("col4", df["TF_CUS"].getItem(1)).withColumn("col5", df["TF_CUS"].getItem(0)).show(2, False)
df = df.withColumn("col4", (df["TF_CUS"].getItem(1))).withColumn("col5", df["TF_CUS"].getItem(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to take the column, and essentially do a simple cast to type array (int), in your case of col4.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("col6", Fcol("col4").cast("array<int>"))
```

Comment: import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = df.withColumn("col6", F.col("col4").cast("array<int>"))

when I ran getting error message ( Spark 2.3.1)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o9162.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`col4`' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast string to array<int>;;